# How to total up array containing durations to minutes?

Tags: php, sql

Need to total up an array of durations formatted such 2:30, 2:49

I tried using

```
 $length = $db->super_query("SELECT * FROM mixes_songs WHERE collectionId = '$albumId'");
$row['length'] =  array_sum($length);
```

but then I found it wouldn't work in this case.

How would I go about totalling up the durations so it will output in minutes? e.g 30 MINS or if >1hr then 1hr 5 mins.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. There is no user input, this is in my backend script. Am I missing something that your saying?

Comment: Usually when I see `'$albumId'` in  SQL it means that your SQL will break sooner or later. Get into a habit of using parameters instead and you won't have to be afraid of it breaking ever.

Comment: Ok I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with super_query and Google isn't helping much. But assuming the mixes_songs table only includes a single field and assuming super_query returns a one-dimensional array of values and assuming you want the output in the format of hh:mm:ss...

```
$length = $db->super_query("SELECT * FROM mixes_songs WHERE collectionId = '$albumId'");
$row['length'] =  timeize(sumSeconds($length));

function sumSeconds(array $minutes): int
{
    $sumMinutes = 0;
    foreach($minutes as $minute) {
        $components = explode(':', $minute);
        $sumMinutes += $components[0] * 60 + $components[1];
    }
    return $sumMinutes;
}

function timeize(int $timeInSeconds): string
{
    $timeize = str_pad((string)floor($timeInSeconds / 3600), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $timeize .= ':' . str_pad((string)floor(($timeInSeconds / 60) % 60), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $timeize .= ':' . str_pad((string)floor($timeInSeconds % 60), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $timeize;
}
```

This also assumes every record in mixes_songs is in the format of mm:ss. The sumSeconds function should include checks for different time formats or the existence of hours.